# Unable to display html input

Tags: javascript, input

So I have two input boxes, one for a username and one for a password. I want to display the inputs back to the user after they hit login, but for some reason all that appears is: [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement] This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <html lang="en-US">
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="java.css">
            </head>
            <title>JAVA</title>
            <body>

                    <form>

                         User name: <input id="uname"></input>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                         Password: <input id="pass"></input>

                        <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
                    </form>

                    <script>

                    var fname = document.getElementById("uname").value;//Username
                    var lname = document.getElementById("pass").value;//Password


                    // Check browser support
                    function login() {
                    if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
                        // Store
                        localStorage.setItem("uname", uname);//Saves username
                        localStorage.setItem("pass", pass);//Saves password
                        // Retrieve
                        document.getElementById("uname").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("uname");//Gets
                        document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("pass");//Gets
                        alert(uname + pass);//Shows account info
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";//Error
                    }
                    }

                    </script>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: may I advise you to store username/password server-side in a database

Comment: What is `uname` and `pass`?

Comment: uname = username pass = password

Comment: use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` to set to set the value of an input-element. So: `document.getElementById("uname").value = localStorage.getItem("uname");`

Comment: What did you expect to appear?

Comment: You try to reference vars `uname` and `pass`, but you have never declared those variables (you have declared var `fname` and `lname`)

Comment: Thanks myFunkyside! But now a new problem has arisen, the alert does not say anything now.

Comment: you should put those two lines where you declare the `vars`, inside the `login()` function

Comment: Thank you! that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a few things mixed up:

1. You got your variables mixed up; you try to reference `uname` and `pass` everywhere, but you have never declared those variables (you have declared `fname` and `lname`).
2. You should declare those variables inside the `login()` function, otherwise they are already declared before the user has actually entered a value into the input fields.
3. You should use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` to set to set the value of an input-element.

Below is your code with those issues fixed:

***fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rx0rjaf3/7/***

---

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form>
        Username: <input id="user" /><br /><br />
        Password: <input id="pass" />
        <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

- `input` elements do not have a closing tag like this: `<input></input>`. Instead, they are self-closing like this: `<input id="user" />`.
- Also try to close your `<br />` tags (like that, instead of `<br>`). Same goes for other elements without a closing tag.
- (I removed some of your HTML code to make the answer more readable. It wasn't necessary for the answer, but that doesn't mean of course that you should remove that on your own site.)

---

**JS**

```
function login() {
    if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
        // Store
        localStorage.setItem("user", document.getElementById("user").value); //Saves username
        localStorage.setItem("pass", document.getElementById("pass").value); //Saves password

        // Retrieve
        var user = localStorage.getItem("user"); //Gets username
        var pass = localStorage.getItem("pass"); //Gets password

        document.getElementById("user").value = user;
        document.getElementById("pass").value = pass;

        alert("username: "+user+"\n"+"password: "+pass); //Shows account info
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";//Error
    }
}
```

- I moved the declaration of the variables to the Retrieve-section. I did this, because you first store the `.values` into `localStorage`, then immediately after you store the `localStorage` into the `.values` again - I assume to make sure they are properly stored.
  But after that, you alert the `vars` you declared before you even stored the `.values` into `localStorage`, so now you still won't know for sure if they are properly stored into `localStorage`, you see? By moving those vars to the Retrieve-section, this problem is fixed.
- I put the JS code in a separate 'file'. This is something I would recommend you to do as well. It's not absolutely necessary, but it is much cleaner.
- In the *jsfiddle* I use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`. This is only to prevent that my, your and everybody else's localStorage doesn't get stuffed with test values.

---

**As a final advice, I highly recommend that you store usernames and passwords in a database on the server, instead of client-side (be it in localStorage, cookies, text files or anything else)!**

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're accessing the `uname` and `pass` automagic global variables, which are set, by the browser to represent the nodes with those `id`s; instead you should use `uname.value` and `pass.value` ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4gpjv5v1/)) or, better, use the variables that you declared earlier in the code (albeit they're set to the initial value of the `<input />` elements and not updated automatically, so I've moved them within the function ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4gpjv5v1/1/)).

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the actual input elements and not their values. You assign the input element values to variables (fname and lname), but then store the elements (uname and pass).

Try this code instead:

```js
// Store
localStorage.setItem("uname", fname);//Saves username
localStorage.setItem("pass", lname);//Saves password
```

I would clean up your variable naming so that the names are more descriptive and match their function.

Also, as stated by another user, storing user credentials in local storage is not a good practice.